# Pricing Model for Databricks Job Cluster

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I have one ADF pipeline per table in my silver and gold layer for transformation logic (Seeing how there is quite a lot of dependencies on these tables).

Example layout:

Silver:

- Silver_Pipeline_Table_1
- Silver_Pipeline_Table_2

Gold:

- Gold_Pipeline_Table_1
- Gold_Pipeline_Table_2

If going for a Job cluster setup, would that kickstart one cluster per Databricks activity? Wouldn't this be pricey? Or does Job clusters distribute the jobs evenly? If I for instance have 40 pipelines each running daily at around the same time with one Databricks Notebook call, would it start 40 job clusters then, each charging X DBU per hour?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the job cluster specificness of your answer, but for our usecase we use an interactive/non-job cluster for our ADF-notebooks. We deal with "small and medium data", not "big data", so we get by with spinning up one interactive cluster which works through all notebooks. If the time to process was more constrained, we would swap to dedicated job cluster for each heavy notebook. I have also questioned the job cluster cost model, where as you say, if you spawn 40 job clusters then you will also pay for 40 * DBUpernotebookcluster. That is too costly for us, we get fine by with one shared interactive cluster.